# Core data : NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This is my datamodel

[image]

In my TableView, I want to display `first` and `city`

The following is my code where I fetch them. I'm getting the `first` data but not the `city`:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if(fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityPerson = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entityPerson];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"first" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortAddress = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"address.city" ascending:NO];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[sortAddress, sortName];
    [request setFetchBatchSize:50];

    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResults = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    fetchedResultsController = fetchedResults;
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

This is where i fetch the results and following is where i try to display the fetched results

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
    TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[TableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                               reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

-(void)configureCell:(TableCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *obj = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

//    cell.lblName.text = @"";
    [cell.lblName setText:[obj valueForKey:@"first"]];
//    cell.lblCity.text = @"";
    [cell.lblCity setText:[obj valueForKey:@"city"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fetched results controller is configured to return Person objects, so you need to reference the properties of the relationship indirectly:

```
[cell.lblCity setText:[obj valueForKeyPath:@"address.city"]];
```

or if you have created a subclass of NSManagedObject, say as `Person`, you can amend your code to:

```
Person *obj = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.lblName.text = obj.first;
cell.lblCity.text = obj.address.city;
```

Comment: @VNJ Sorry, I had used `valueForKey:` where I should have `valueForKeyPath:`  - I have amended my answer to correct.